# when i was using PUT method in postman through Basic Auth i got an error ,i was working on django rest-framework

Tags: django, postman

```
{
      "detail":"Unsupported media type \"text/plain\" in request."
}
```

[image: this image is from postman]

Comment: i think it is something to do with the body of data you are giving to `PUT`

Comment: Can you post what your request looks like?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please have a read through [ask] and especially how to create [mcve]. From the information you provided it is not possible to give you a helpful answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Its occure because of content type of your request .

1. first check your views content type. 2.change content type according to view in postman .

For example :

Header -> add 
key: “Content-Type” 
value: “application/json”

Comment: Thanks! it saves me!!

Answer (score 6):

Below the settings bar there is a "Content-Type" option try changing it to JSON[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
def do(method ='get', data={}, is_json =True):
headers = {}
if is_json:
    headers['content-type'] ='application/json'
    data = json.dumps(data)
r = requests.request(method, ENDPOINT, data=data, headers = headers )
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
return r


do(method='post', data={"content": "some cool api ", 'user':1})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.